# Error unmet dependencies systemd on sudo apt upgrade

Tags: apt, upgrade, dpkg, dependencies

I am trying to update and upgrade my machine via command line.
But when I try to run `sudo apt upgrade` I get the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpam-systemd : Depends: systemd (= 229-4ubuntu21.2)
 systemd : Depends: libsystem0 (= 229-4ubuntu19) but 229-4ubuntu21.2 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f
```

So I tried `sudo apt -f install` but then I get following error:

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/systemd_229-4ubuntu21.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 too-long line or missing newline in '/var/lib/dpkg/info/systemd.triggers'
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/systemd_229-4ubuntu21.2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I can `sudo reboot` without any errors.

What is causing that issue and how can I solve it?

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt update` followed by `sudo apt dist-upgrade`?

Comment: I did `sudo apt update` before running `sudo apt upgrade`. It did not return any errors. Can I run `sudo apt dist-upgrade` before upgrade?

Comment: Yes, you can. It will upgrade all packages with new dependencies (stayin on 16.04 of course).

Comment: The problem is clearly stated in the second error message: There's a typo or corrupt line in the file `/var/lib/dpkg/info/systemd.triggers`. That bad line is preventing the new version of systemd from installing, which in turn is blocking libpam-systemd. Please edit your question to show us the complete contents of that file.

Comment: Have you examined Ubuntu `systemd` bugs for similar cases? This one looks vaguely pertinent: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1570310